# Importing class objects in Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, class, import, python-import

I am creating a PyStudentManager app and trying to import my 'HighSchoolStudent' class from my 'classes.py' file (HighSchoolStudents was inherited from Student):

```
students = []

class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, student_id=332):
        self.name=  name
        self.student_id = student_id
        students.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Student " + self.name

    def get_name_capitalize(self):
        return self.name.capitalize()

    def get_school_name(self):
        return self.school_name


class HighSchoolStudent(Student):

    def get_school_name(self):
        return "This is a High School student"

    def get_name_capitalize(self):
        original_value = super().get_name_capitalize()
        return original_value + "-HS"
```

The following is me importing in my'webapp.py' file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request

import classes.HighSchoolStudent

# ...
```

I've a bunch of different ways of writing the import statement, I think the Pluralsight course I was following on Introductory Python was using a previous version of python, which is why I am stuck, Thanks.

[image: If somebody wants to describe file tree]

Comment: Can you show your file structure? Where is classes.py located and where is webapp.py located?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like:

```
from classes import HighSchoolStudent
```

If you want to import it with an alias, say, `HSStudent`, then you can do:

```
from classes import HightSchoolStudent as HSStudent
```

I'm assuming that the `classes.py` is in your current directory. If it is in a separate directory, you will need to give the path appropriately. But the import statement syntax will be the same.

Comment: I try using that same import statement, but I come up with a warning: 'unused import statement'

Comment: @ChristopherRoper It means that you imported a package but not you are not using it anywhere in your code. This won't prevent you from running your code, it's just a warning. But if you are not going to use it, don't import it. If my answer helped you to import, please accept it as the answer.